# Crystal report logo image does not show all the time on the report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, itext, parallel.foreach

Good Day,

I have a console application that has a crystal report that has an image. I will run the report use exporttostream and store the exported report within a varbinary field in sqlserver 2012. I will then select batches of these reports and concatenate them into 1 pdf file using itextsharp. The logo on the report shows on some pages not all. Any ideas why this may be happening. I am also using parallel processing(Parallel.For) when running this application.
Any ideas why this may be happening? or what is the best way to get this image embedded on the report to always show?
I tried running the same code but with only 1 parrallel process (i.e. will do sequentially) and all the images appeared in the pdf. Why is paralell processing not rendering images properly?
Thanks in advance

******edit******
Code for concatenating pdfs

```
Document document = null;

for ( int i=1; i <= numbatches;i++)
{

    String printer_file_prefix = dll.Print.getPrinterFilePrefix(connectionString, bill_type_id.ToString());
    batchnumberpadded = i.ToString();
    batchnumberpadded = batchnumberpadded.PadLeft(3, '0');

    printerfilename = printer_file_prefix + oneup_number + batch_id + batchnumberpadded;//eg D_G123456CUST001

    BatchPrintFilePath = Globals.printer_filelocation_prefix + printerfilename + ".pdf";

     document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(BatchPrintFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite));
    document.Open();

    using (SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetPrinterFiles", sconn))
        {

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch_num", i);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maximumRows",Globals.print_batch);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@archive_process_instance_no", archive_process_instance_no);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch_id", @batch_id);

            sconn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.Default))
            {

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader((byte[])dr.GetValue(0)));
                }

                dr.Close();
                sconn.Close();
            }
            sconn.Close();
        }
    }

    if (copy != null)
        copy.Close();
    if (document.IsOpen())
        document.Close();


}//end for
```

Comment: Please clarify: how are you concatenating the files? There are a lot of *really bad* examples out there that use `Document` and `PdfWriter` (which is obviously the wrong way) instead of using `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` (which is the correct way). This question is unanswerable if you don't provide more data.

Comment: Sorry about that I edited my question. I did not know what may be causing the problem so did not know what parts of the code will assist

Comment: Start by removing `copy.Close()`. If you want to keep that line, close the `Document` *before* closing the `PdfCopy` instance. Now we can see your code, but we still don't know what's wrong. Where are the logos you're talking about? Maybe they aren't present anywhere due to some reason outside of iText. Is there a way you can provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: The logo  is within the crystal report. I dont think I'll be able to provide an SSCEE because of comapny policy. sorry

Comment: Isn't the problem caused by the fact that the logo is never added? iText doesn't have any reason to drop specific content. I think the logo was never there to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the replies. The logo was somehow added as an OLE object. I added the logo as a picture and placed the jpg logo file within an images folder in the project and ran the process and it seems to work now. Thank you for your assistance